# How to configure Spring Boot to start Tomcat after some component is constructed?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I would like Tomcat in Spring application to open port after specified component initializes himself, so my load balancer may start to send requests only after the app is ready.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot starts the Servlet container after singleton beans are initialized. Unless your bean is lazy or is implementing [`Lifecycle`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) there is no need to configure anything.

You probably should configure your load balancer to use [Actuators `/health` endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) response. Requests should be routed only when `/health` returns `{"status": "UP"}`. If you have a custom resource you should implement a new `HealthIndicator` bean to check it's status.